# How do I refer to an embedded notification within chrome in python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, notifications, webdriver

[Example of the embedded notification within chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovj9P.png)

Hi everyone, I hope you are well. I am using python selenium webdriver in order to navigate through a website protected by Duo Security, and I want to make it so that when this embedded notification pops out, it will close it and proceed with the rest of the commands I have printed out. There is not really a way of reproducing this apart from going to a website with Duo security (this is my university website which you need a login for) so I unfortunately cannot help in that regard.

I am simply wondering how I may refer to this element in my python code so that it can click the close button, seeing as how it is not an element within the webpage (i.e., I cannot inspect element it) but rather it is a chrome notification type-thing.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: How do you expected people to answer to this without any data ?
Question is unclear. You could have run your brower's inspector for the close button and perhaps posted the corresponding source, and your selenium sources.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you've provided, the 'embedded notification' seems to be some customized JavaScript alert/confirm.

Check [official Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/alerts/) to see how to handle it.

In a nutshell, you have to use driver.switch_to.alert and then accept/dismiss it.